# Liferay Portlet check the view state

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

Is it possible to check what state the portlet is in (meaning: maximized, normal, minimized) in the portlet Controller (or portlet view JSP)? I am using Liferay 6.1.0 and Spring Portlet MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the portlet `windowState` from the `portletRequest.getWindowState()`. Compare the value with the `javax.portlet.WindowState.NORMAL`, `javax.portlet.WindowState.MAXIMIZED`, `javax.portlet.WindowState.MINIMIZED`.

Comment: Sorry I am deleting the post that I had mentioned. windowState is not part of pageContext because of the liferay-theme:defineObjects Actually I checked the jsp and it was directly available to me and I thought it was in pageContext but it was coming from init.jsp of the portal. However you can retrieve renderRequest or actionRequest and from that you can get the windowState. Thanks for bringing into my notice Felix :)